# How to check Promise's current state?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I need to check for debugging purposes if a promise is already resolved -  something like `p.isResolved()`. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Promise.state ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise

Comment: @shershen That is not an exposed property.

Answer (score 4):

Trigger a log when it is resolved or emit a event if you want it be handled somewhere else:

```
triggerMyPromiseMethod()
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('Promise resolved', response)

        // continue...
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Something went wrong with my Promise', err)
    })
```

Comment: agreed with @Claudio Bredfeldt the only way to debug your code is by using logs ..

Comment: So I understand by your answer that there's no way to check Promise's state outside of the promise context, right?

Comment: "By design, the instant state and value of a promise cannot be inspected synchronously from code, without calling the then() method.", MDN Promise Documentation